# Trouble Formatting BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, boxlayout

I want to layout 6 components, vertically aligned in one column. In addition, I want a blank space of 200 pixels before the first component in the column. I have the following code:

```
   public class MongoMusicApplet extends JApplet{

  //*****main menu objects********
  private JPanel mainMenuPanel;
  private JButton buildingButton;
  private JTextField text;

  public void init(){

     setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

     mainMenuPanel=new JPanel();

     buildingButton=new JButton("Graph-Building Mode");
     text=new JTextField(20);
     JLabel label1=new JLabel("Help us improve by entering");
     JLabel label2=new JLabel("OR");
     JLabel label3=new JLabel("Enter the name of an artist");
     JLabel label4=new JLabel("to enter Discovery Mode");

     mainMenuPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,200)));

     label1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
     mainMenuPanel.add(label1);

     buildingButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
     mainMenuPanel.add(buildingButton);

     ...add all other components in this order: label 2, label3, text, label4...

     add(mainMenuPanel);
  } 
}
```

And I get the following layout:
[image]

So first off, it seems that the createRigidArea is creating space before the column starts, and also in between some of the components in the column. Is there a way to make it only create space before the first component in the column?

And second, since I chose the alignment to be Y_AXIS, why are the components not arranged vertically, with one component per row? I also tried to use GridLayout(0,1), but that gave me the exact same layout. How can I force these components into one vertical column?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Use an `EmptyBorder` for the 200px gap before the first component.  And see  also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, even with any setSize methods removed, I still am not getting the components vertically stacked

Comment: *"I still am not getting.."*  I am still not seeing your MCVE.. And I asked you a question that you have ignored.

Comment: Figured it out on my own. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I found out I needed to change this line:

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

to this:

```
mainMenuPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainMenuPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS))
```

since I am adding the components to the mainMenuPanel, not the applet's content pane directly.

It was a dumb error, but I'm just adding this in case anyone stumbles upon this later